# Create a Nested Loop on Java

Tags: java, loops, nested

I'm a newbie on Java Programming and self studying at home. I got this problem on a book and cant figure it out:

Write a java program that would display the following using nested loops:

```
6
12 13
19 20 21
```

I can create the same pattern using the following

```
    for (int x = 1; x<=3; x++) {
        for (int y = 1; y <= x; y++) {
            System.out.print("*");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
```

but I don't have any idea how to increment those numbers by +6 or +1. hope someone helps. thanks a lot.

Comment: Try to understand the patter..print 6 in the first line...print 6*2 in the next line followed by 6*2+1...this follows..

Comment: hint: try to add an additional variable, that gets incremented by 1 when you are in the same row, by 6 when you go to the next row

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If this is your expected output:

```
6
12 13 
19 20 21 
26 27 28 29
```

then this code will output it:

```
int n = 4;
System.out.println(6);
for (int i=2; i <= n; i++) {
    for (int j=i-2,k=0; k < i; j++,k++) {
        System.out.print(6*i+j + " ");
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

Comment: if you want to print the first element in the loop then add 
`if(j<0) System,.out.print(6*i);`

Comment: Nice code...it looks just like mine except that it won't give the desired output.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code:

```
for (int i=1; i <= 3; ++i) {
    for (int j=0; j < i; ++j) {
        if (j > 0) {
            System.out.print(" ");
        }
        System.out.print(i*6 + j);
    }
    System.out.print("\n");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
int n = 3;
        for (int i=1; i <= n; ++i) {
            for (int j=0; j < i; ++j) {
                if (j==0){
                       System.out.println(i*6);

                } else {
                       System.out.print(i*6+j);
                       System.out.print(" ");

                }

            }
        }
```